# Injected script was not load

Tags: google-chrome-extension

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Inject Scripts",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "*://*/*"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "js": [
            "content.js"
        ]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": [
            "every site .js"
        ],
        "matches": []
    }]
}
```

**content.js**

```
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ˋ<script src="${chrome.runtime.getURL('every site .js')}"></script>ˋ)
```

**every site .js**

```
console.log('injected')
```

`<script>` was inserted to `<head>` successful with the `src="chrome-extension://<extension ID>/every site .js"` attribute but there is neither `console.log` output nor **Error** message.

I installed my extension locally by enabling "Developer mode" and "Load unpacked" in "chrome://extensions/".

Do I need to specify "permissions" in **manifest.json**?

Comment: Neither insertAdjacentHTML nor innerHTML run `script` elements. This is intentional. Use document.createElement and appendChild, example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, I missed that info.